# PowerShell Foreach Out-Put Issue

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am trying to spit out the output of my command into a csv. The best I can do is to get it to display on the powershell Screen. How can I accomplish this?

```
 $computers = Get-Content -Path C:\folder\file.csv
 $numbers = @($computers)

 Foreach ($i in $computers) {
   Get-adcomputer $i -properties CanonicalName 

 }  Export-CSV c:\folder2\finalfile.csv
```

If tried different examples in the FAQ but they don't work for my needs.

I appreciate the help.

Thanks,

Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You never send any objects to `Export-CSV`. `Foreach($item in $array)` can't be used with the pipeline (if you were missing a `|`) so you would have to store the results in a list or array first. I'd switch to `Foreach-object` and the pipeline.
- `Get-Content` is for reading text (ex. one computer per line), however your filetype suggests csv (usually multi-column), which you would read with `Import-CSV`. Since you say that it works, I'll assume it's actually just a list of names, so I kept `Get-Content`.
- `$numbers` is unused

Try:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\folder\file.csv | Foreach-Object {
    Get-ADComputer -Identity $_ -Properties CanonicalName
} | Export-CSV c:\folder2\finalfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank You Frode! Your help is greatly appreciated.